# SetText() Method in android for recycler Adapter

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming in android and I am working on recycler view adapter for which I am not able to work with the setText() method in the Adapter
[image: Image for reference]

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position) {

```
    NoteModel noteModel = mNoteList.get(position);
    holder.tvNote.setText(noteModel.getNote());//Error in this
    holder.tvAddedOn.setText(addedON);//Error in this
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    String addedON = String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(new Date(noteModel.getAddedOn())));

}
```

I tried to view all the references which can help me to set the text but not able to find one, is there any other alternative for this??

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve static data or dynamic? Please share your error message.

Comment: I am not getting any error its just that I am not able to retrieve the settext method and I am trying to retrieve dynamic data here

Answer (score 0):

The Adapter does not know, or rather care, what type of items it contains, meaning editing those items is nothing the adapter does. What it does know however, is the items' id's. You can get those by using [getItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemId(int)). You can then use the id to find the respective View and change whatever you need to change there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. **Just try to Re-arrange it**

   ```
   NoteModel noteModel = mNoteList.get(position);
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
   String addedON = String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(new 
   Date(noteModel.getAddedOn())));
   holder.tvNote.setText(noteModel.getNote());//Put it at the bottom
   holder.tvAddedOn.setText(addedON);//Put it at the bottom
   ```

Comment: It still did not work for me, the issue is only with the setText however I am able to see the method for text allignment() but not setText()